# Mongoose and limiting the results of field schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called "Binders"
In this collection I have a field called "docs" that references a "Docs" schema

I want to pull a "Binder" by id with findOne() which is no problem.

But I want to limit the returned "Docs" by a field comparison

I am somewhat new to mongoose but if i had pseudo my query...

```
Binder.findOne({_id: req.binder._id}, {$where {docs.type = 'type1'}}, function(error, binder) { 

// So this would return my full binder but only the docs where their .type = 'type1'

});
```

Where I get lost is the limiting based on a Schema

```
{$where {docs.type = 'type1'}}
```

So if I pulled a binder and it had 50 docs, but none of the docs were of type1 I would still get my binder info, however there would be no documents in the Docs field.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following you right and `docs` is an array, then you can use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/#_S_elemMatch) projection operator to do this:

```js
Binder.findOne({_id: req.binder._id}, {docs: {$elemMatch: {type: 'type1'}}}, ...
```

Comment: Hi $elemMatch worked great thank you!. Question I also tried it in another part of the project where I had to nest it so like docs.users {$elemMatch.... but it says you can't use elemMatch on nested values... ideas?

Comment: @user324245 I'm not sure I understand...probably best to ask that as a separate question.